# What is the difference between a yum group and a yum module in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8?

Tags: rhel, package-management, yum

In their Red Hat Certified System Administrator training, Red Hat defines a Module in RHEL8 as "a set of package RPMs that belong together." However, I am also aware of a very similar definition of a "group" as in `yum groupinstall 'KDE'`. What is the difference between a Module and a group in RHEL8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modules are versioned, so you can enable a particular version of a module and it will stay with that version of the module during updates.  Yum groups don’t have that capability.

For example, you do `dnf module enable perl:5.24`, and then install perl packages, they’ll remain the 5.24 packages when you do a dnf update.  Red Hat can release updates, bug fixes and security fixes and they’ll be applied.  But there’s also a perl:5.26 module with newer versions of packages that won’t be installed because it isn’t enabled.

Comment: So it's essentially a way to "freeze" a group of packages at a specific version for compatibility reasons, but still also get essential security updates?

Comment: Packages can get updates within the module too. It’s for getting a particular version of a group of packages that are all built with each other in mind. For example, there are php:7.1 and php:7.2 modules that have all the dependencies within the modules.

Comment: Ah got it. So the module itself is versioned, which could include various package versions that are all meant to work together within the module.

Comment: @the_endian exactly!